# Form not submitting correctly in Chrome (data not saving)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-chrome

I have a form that I cannot modify the source of, but need to add additional actions so I added an external js file that contains this:

```
$("input[title=Save]").click(function(){
alert("Profile saved");
window.location.replace("/newpage.asp");
});
```

All works fine in IE and FF (after the Save button submits the form, an alert appears and then it redirects you).

But in Chrome everything seems to work but the contents of the form do not submit correctly, that is to say if you reload the page the fields aren't saved.

This is the button

```
<input class="rButton" type="button" value="Save" title="Save" onclick="javascript:submitME(0,0);return false;" />
```

Comment: Can this work? Can you redirect to another page to process a form like that? I though if you use `window.location` theres no POST or GET passed... You are just forwarded... Or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Yes it doesn't replace or prevent the submit action, and the alert stops the script until the user clicks ok, then it continues (and redirects). Not clean but I have no access to any source.

Comment: I'm just curious about event delegation here, maybe Chrome is firing this _before_ and the problem is that the page will probably have to reload in order to submit, or if its using ajax you'd have to find another way to delay your event until you know the submit has completed...

Comment: The values of input elements are not supposed to be preserved after reloading the page.  This is your responsibility, you cannot expect the browser to do this.  This is something you must do on server side. (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: Yes inputs will be the same after the page reloads - they are part of the form HTML. The issue from what I can tell is IE and FF continue with the form submission behind the `alert("Profile saved");` whereas Chrome does not. This is the most reliable way I've found to force a redirect client-side after a form submit. If anyone has any ideas to redirect a page after form submit I would love to try them.

Comment: @Emmanuel Delay Oh sorry - you mean the values in the form fields. They are being pulled from a sql database, and the html form is for updating them. So yes, when submitting the form the values remain. The default action is to reload the same page. I'm trying to change this